# Copy and paste hyperlink in flutter

Tags: flutter, hyperlink, copy, clipboard, paste

I have a text and a URL link like this:

Title
https://example.net

Now I can copy them to the clipboard and paste them separately like above but I would like to paste them so it is a text with hyperlink, like this:

Title

How do I do this in flutter?

I have tried doing the following

```
final title = 'Title';
final url = 'https://example.net';
inal htmlLink = '<a href="$url">$title</a>';
final uri = Uri.dataFromString(htmlLink, mimeType: 'text/html');
```

Comment: check this article,  https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/206/how-to-create-text-hyperlink-in-flutter/